How to manage RabbitMQ overflow in a Quarkus/Smallrye RabbitMQ publisher?
In a Quarkus 3.8.3 application with smallrye-reactive-messaging-rabbitmq I am struggling to make the RabbitMQ "overflow" property throw an error in my publisher when my queue is full and I try to publish another one:
From the rabbitMQ side, I am using an "at least once dead lettering" configuration, which means quorum queues with overflow: reject-publish + dead-letter-strategy=at-least-once.
In the Quarkus properties, I have configured the "publish-confirms" + a "default-ttl" for published messages like this (btw, I didn't find these properties in the config reference doc?):
mp.messaging.outgoing.commands-channel.publish-confirms=true
mp.messaging.outgoing.commands-channel.default-ttl=1000

When I publish a message once the queue is full, using mutinyEmitter.sendMessage(Msg), I think RabbitMQ is correctly not confirming the message published, but my Uni never fails. And the timeout "default-ttl" also doesn't seem to change anything. I have to use something like this, which is of course not reactive, and does not differentiate a "real" timeout from a nack:
.await().atMost(Duration.of(5, ChronoUnit.SECONDS));

What is the correct way to be sure that the message was taken into account by imperative publishers (For example here I am publishing a message from a JAX-RS resource)? Ideally using reactive ways of working, I would prefer non-blocking...
thx.
